# Unable to get unread count from Google Reader using OAuth2

Tags: java, oauth-2.0

I have been able to get list of subscription from Google Reader using OAuth 2. Subscription list response gives URL of feeds. Further to this I am interested in also getting unread count for a given access_token(user) ?

The URL which I am using for getting subscription list is : https://www.google.com/reader/api/0/subscription/list

Looked online to get help; but most places its been done using user's id and password. But i am interested in doing the same using OAuth2.

Also i explored [OAuth 2.0 playground of Google](https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/); but haven't got any help so far. 
I am doing it in Java, in case it adds some value.